# Overlaying text on video element

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, html5-video

I've got a full screen div which is set to play a video but requires me to put some HTML over the top of it. However whenever I place this, I can see the test button load up and then vanish when the video loads.

What am I doing wrong?

Snippet:

```
<div class="row black-bg">
<section class="Splash">
    <div class="video-container">
          <video autoplay muted loop="true">
            <source type="video/mp4" src="/backdropvideo.mp4">
          </video>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-5" style="z-index:22222;"><button> test </button></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.Splash {
    position: relative;
    width: 90vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 95vh;
    min-height: 710px;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:black;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gamesplayed {
    background-image: url(assets/GamesBanner.png);
    background-color: black;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    min-height:20vh;
}

.video-container video {
  /* Make video to at least 100% wide and tall */
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 

  /* Setting width & height to auto prevents the browser from stretching or squishing the video */
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  /* Center the video */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remove the z-index from the inline style on the test button, and create a style rule for `mt-5` (I picked that as it was undefined in the example, you can add the styling as a different class if needed) as follows then the button remains visible over the video:

```
.mt-5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

obviously depending on the z-index of other items on the page you may need to adjust this, but the key was adding the `position` and `top` attributes

Comment: Perfect, thanks for steering me in the right direction